# What is the (void*) type? And how can I dereference it?

Tags: c, pointers

Suppose you got a struct like this below:

```
struct msgbuf {
 char msgtext[MAX_LENGTH];
}
```

And you cast it to (void*)

```
struct msgbuf m;
m.msgtext = "Text";
(void*) m;
```

---

1. What is (void*) and what value does it contain relating to the struct?
2. How can I get the value of msgtext of m after the cast? (I'm assuming by dereferencing it)

---

EDIT: To elaborate without posting too much code I want to pass a struct to a POSIX thread I am creating.

```
th_ret = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, method_called, (void*) m);

void *method_called( void *rsp)
{
//get text from *rsp, which should be m passed
}
```

Comment: Why would you try to cast a struct to a pointer type?

Comment: It is not possible to cast struct type to `void *` type. This `(void*) m;` is non-compilable. If your code is intended to be C code, then this `m.msgtext = "Text";` is also non-compilable. Arrays in C are not assignable. You need to provide a more meaningful code sample. It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @BDillan: Your edit is non-compilable either. One more time: it is not possible to cast struct type to pointer type. There's no such feature in C language. In a typical usage with `pthread_create` it would be `(void *) &m`. Note: `&m`, not just `m`.

Comment: (void*) &m may compile, but that may well not be safe as the last argument to pthread_create due to lifetime issues.

Comment: @Martin James: Whether there are lifetime issues there or not is impossible to say without seeing more context. And that's a completely different question anyway.

Comment: @AnT it is, but why not stave it off now?  This question is not good, and a later one about segfaults in the thread when dereferencing the parameter would be even more unwelcome.

Comment: @Martin James: I don't see the problem here. I pass pointers to local variables to threads every day, when I know that the thread will end before the lifetime of the local variable ends. There's nothing wrong with it. And in this case we don't even know if `m` is local or static.

Comment: @AnT indeed, hence 'MAY well not be safe'.  In general, if the thread intends sole use of the parameter, it should control its lifetime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to pass `&m` to the `pthread_create()` (e.g. pass the struct by reference). `&m` is the address of your struct, and an address is compatible with a `void *`.

Although a struct can be passed by *value* if declared explicitly that way in the function declaration, it is risky and frowned upon. When sent through a `void *` argument, structs *must* be passed by reference, for one obvious reason - a struct cannot *generally* be contained in a `sizeof(void *)` amount memory.

`pthread_create()` uses the `void *` argument type to be generic as possible, e.g. to accommodate a variety of fixed-length types that can fit in a *small* amount of stack space, where larger amounts of data can be *indirectly* referenced by passing a pointer to them instead.

Where the function argument is a `void *`, and where struct is defined:

```
 struct {
   .
   .
   .
 } myStruct;
```

This is legal:

```
 (void *)&myStruct  // pass by reference
```

This is illegal (compiler disallows it):

```
 (void *)myStruct  // pass by value
```

Sometimes people  pass a simple `int` or `unsigned int` to their thread, because it is simpler, and sufficient for their need, but, commonly, a pointer to a `struct` is passed by reference to convey an arbitrary amount of contextually relevant data.

An `int` (and several other data types) can be cast into a `void *` and vice versa, for example, if you just want to pass an integer, or float. What's important is that how you pass the argument is in agreement with how you interpret it later.

Calling:

```
   struct msgbuf {
       char msgtext[MAX_LENGTH];
   } m;
   th_ret = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, method_called, &m);
```

Handling:

```
   void *method_called(void *rsp) {
       struct msgbuf *m = rsp;
       printf("%s\n", m->msgtext);
   }
```

Comment: How can I dereference &m? If I  want to access the data/value in the memory that (void *) holds?

Comment: Hang on, I'm updating my answer, it's not right yet. I'll let you know.

Comment: @BDillan: If you want to update your question, you have to edit the question, not switch to something else in the comments.

Comment: Neither cast is actually necessary. C language will convert to `void *` implicitly. C language will also convert from `void *` implicitly.

Comment: @BDillan my example is done. Ant says 2nd cast isn't necessary, probably isn't.  Try it without it and if compiler complains (probably won't) add it back.

Comment: @BDillan, thanks for the vote, also I fixed the printf() to refer to m, not msgbuf

Comment: "What's important is that how you pass the argument is in agreement with how you interpret it later." - The Central Dogma of Computer Programming! ;)

Comment: Why this useless cast `(struct msgbuf *)rsp`?